# Include Ubuntu Font in Game

Tags: ubuntu-font-family

Am I allowed to include the (unmodified) Ubuntu font in my game and distribute it together?
The situation is, that I like the font, but because the game is written in python, it also runs under windows and there nobody has this font installed. I would put it in a resources folder as I downloaded it (with license, and so on).

Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From  http://font.ubuntu.com/about/:

> Both the final font Truetype/OpenType files and the design files used to produce the font family are distributed under an [open licence](http://font.ubuntu.com/licence/) and you are expressly encouraged to experiment, modify, share and improve. The typeface is sans-serif, uses OpenType features and is manually hinted for clarity on desktop and mobile computing screens.

Next step: consult a lawyer about the licence and what it allows.

Comment: I think consulting a lawyer wouldn't be necessary after carefully reading the license once.

Comment: So I am allowed, I think.